# C++: properly freeing a pointer to a struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, null, free

So I am trying to learn C++ (and a little bit of C) and was wondering if there is a truly proper way to free a pointer to a struct. There is an example of what I am talking about below.

```
#include <iostream>

struct guy {
  int the_data;
};

int main() {
  guy the_guy, *ptr;

  ptr = &the_guy;
  ptr->the_data = 3;
  ptr = NULL;
  free(ptr);
  std::cout << "whaddup guy's data: " << the_guy.the_data <<std::endl;
}
```

I'm mostly curious because I have seen answers that say you need to set the pointer to `NULL` after you free it? This can't be right because whenever I try that I get an error at compile time.

Thoughts?

Comment: You should only pass to `free` things you received from `malloc`. (You don't "free" pointers, but what they point to.)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `ptr = NULL; free(ptr);` is harmless because `free(NULL);` is defined to do nothing. But you should add `#include <cstdlib>` for using `free()`.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `free` or `malloc` in C++ period. Use `new` and `delete` instead.

Comment: to expand molbdnilo's answer, 
if you program c++ you should use the keywords new and delete.

Comment: @MikeCAT He shouldn't be using `free` at all since it is not dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @MikeCAT the error i get is `free(): invalid pointer` I guess because you can't free a a null ptr?

Comment: @Jflee No because `free(NULL);` and `delete NULL;` are safe and do nothing.

Comment: @MikeCAT You only use free() to delete heap memory alocated with malloc(). In your case the pointer points to local (stack) memory 'the_guy'. When you try to free ptr that points to not-malloc-allocated the_guy you get invalid pointer error. In code you provided you free(NULL) which is no-op.

Comment: Also errors caused by freeing not dynamically allocated pointer should be in run time, not compile time.

Comment: I wonder where you are learning C. That place should have told you that you don't free arbitrary pointers, but only pointers pointing at memory allcoated with `malloc` or `realloc`.

Comment: @MikeCAT also yeah i goofed and thought it was compile time because i build and run using a script that suppresses output :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`guy the_guy` here is a local variable which lifetime is defined by its scope!
Free memory of local variable is just Undefined Behavior and you are lucky that it crashes.

`free` can be used only on memory which was allocated by `malloc` (or `calloc` or `realloc`).
In all other cases it will lead to undefined behavior, so do not do it.

Comment: So in order to avoid dangling pointers to structs i should just set the pointer to `NULL`, correct?

Comment: More like your code should be written is such way that it is obvious if pointer owns memory or not. In your example pointer do not owns memory.

Comment: we have year 2021 so just use C++11 `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` which will free memory for you when needed.